# Cannot create different random numbers in loop

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and am having difficulty understanding where I am going wrong in this random number guessing game I have created. I have tried to add a random.next command in the do while loop on line 30, when I run the program it says my guess is either too high or too low, I do not understand what is going wrong. Here is the unfinished code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int numberToGuess = random.Next(100) + 1;
        int userGuess = 0;
        string name;

        Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
        name = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("In this game you need to guess which number the computer has picked in the range of 1 to 100."
            + Environment.NewLine + "If the number you enter is too high or too low the program will display this, " +
            Environment.NewLine + "try to make the least amount of guesses as possible!" + Environment.NewLine 
            + "==========================================================================================================");

        do
        {

            do
            {
                Console.Write("Enter your guess: ");
                userGuess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                if (userGuess > numberToGuess)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(userGuess + " is too high!");
                }
                else if (userGuess < numberToGuess)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(userGuess + " is too low!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(userGuess + " SPOT ON! Congratulations.");
                }

                numberToGuess = random.Next(100) + 1;

            } while (userGuess != numberToGuess);

            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue?");
        } while (Console.ReadLine().ToUpper() == "YES");


    }
```

If I remove numberToGuess = random.Next(100) + 1; the code works fine but repeats the same random number.

Please Help.

Comment: Are you kidding me? you are guessing 1 from 100 possible numbers. chance to guess correct is 1%. use smaller range like 0 to 10.

Comment: The main issue is your algo, Perhaps the random rumber is set earlier, and user have multiple try to guess it.

Comment: It is part of my university assignment, it has to be in this range.

Comment: You have to put `numberToGuess = random.Next(100) + 1;` outside of the loop, otherwise the number is regenerated each time

Comment: ok, for sake of debugging keep it down. then see if it works or not

Comment: Everytime the user makes a guess that is wrong you change the random number - I am guessing you want to keep the same number until the guess is right. You need to move  _"numberToGuess = random.Next(100) + 1;"_ outside the inner loop - so after _"Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue?");"_

Comment: I have tried to change the variable names, have tried to just declare numberToGuess but it does the same thing! I have been stuck on this for ages.

Comment: It works!!! Thank you so much

Comment: @Bidou `numberToGuess`  is already outside loop. or did OP edit his post?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary : No edit - the line that needed moving is directly above _"} while (userGuess != numberToGuess);"_ - so inside the innermost loop.

Comment: @ M.kazem Akhgary the line he was saying was not outside the loop which is why the same number was being re-generated.

Comment: you actually doing it wrong. you have to put it inside loop but outside inner loop... so it should be after first `do` but before second `do`

Comment: Thanks for the help guys especially @Bidou would have taken me hours to figure out!

Comment: A better solution to my original comment is just to have a single statement creating the random number at the top of the first do statement, the second one can then be removed as it is no longer required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debug your application replacing

```
Console.Write("Enter your guess: ");
```

With

```
Console.Write("Enter your guess (" + numberToGuess + "): ");
```

You will see that the numberToGuess is changing every time... you should comment that line and use only the fist random number generated.

Answer (score 0):

Your number of guess range is very high 1 to 100 and after every time you are generating random number again. Just reduce you size of random generator number for example

```
 int numberToGuess = random.Next(5) + 1;
```

First check its working good or not then think about expanding it.

Comment: That does not fix the problem - see the comments above.

Answer (score -3):

This method will return a truly random number.

`Public Shared Function RandomInteger(min As Integer, max As Integer) As Integer
            Dim Rand As New System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider
            Dim scale As UInteger = UInteger.MaxValue
            While scale = UInteger.MaxValue
                ' Get four random bytes.
                Dim four_bytes As Byte() = New Byte(3) {}
                Rand.GetBytes(four_bytes)`

```
            ' Convert that into an uint.
            scale = BitConverter.ToUInt32(four_bytes, 0)
        End While

        ' Add min to the scaled difference between max and min.
        Return CInt(min + (max - min) * (scale / CDbl(UInteger.MaxValue)))
    End Function
```

Comment: Are you answering the question posed? If so please explain how this fixes the problem.

Comment: How does that answer the OP's question? Not to mention it's in VB whereas the OP is working in C#...

Comment: This method will return a true random number. For C# go to: http://converter.telerik.com/